# Draw multiple shapes as one

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on a javascript application where I draw a map using polygons on a html canvas, these polygons have different colors and shadows depending on what they represent.
For example, forests are represented by a green fill color with a large shadow, of course not all forests are connected to each other, but do sometimes get really close to other forest polygons.

The problem is now that in some cases the shadow of one forest is drawn on top of another forest, which kills the whole effect.

Is there a way to fill all those (for example) forest polygons at once to make sure the shadow (and other styling) is correct?
Or what could be another solution to solve this issue?

Current situation:
[image]

Comment: Draw all shadow before draw the forest. If its possible to separate them.

Comment: @fuyushimoya I was thinking about that, but wouldn't that significantly increase the time it would take to render everything?

Comment: I think it'll affect, but I'm not sure there's other way to avoid that shadow issue.

Comment: Consider running some small unit tests to try @fuyushimoya's suggested technique to see how much it affects performance. If you can see an exponential increase on a small scale, there is a good chance it will either scale linearly or exponentially upon full-level implementation to you and your user's detriment.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck and `@fuyushimoya` thanks, I'll give it a try and see how it turns out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I found a very simple way of achieving my goal,

It's possible to create multiple polygons before actually filling them, you don't have to start a new path for every single polygon as long as you always go back to the point where you started creating the polygon

Example:

```
        c2.beginPath();

        //Create polygon 1
        c2.moveTo(8,8); //Move "cursor" to starting position
        c2.lineTo(8,16);
        c2.lineTo(16,16);
        c2.lineTo(16,8);
        c2.lineTo(8,8); //End the polygon at the starting position

        //Create polygon 2
        c2.moveTo(32,8);
        c2.lineTo(32,16);
        c2.lineTo(48,16);
        c2.lineTo(48,8);
        c2.lineTo(32,8);

        c2.closePath();

        //Fill both polygons
        c2.fill();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use global composite operations. If you use `source-out` as composite operation the overlapping areas of your forests should not be drawn. I'm not sure if this also works with shadows though...

See
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing
for more details.

An additional note: You might need to use the state-stack and draw the forests on an own stack layer. Otherwise all shapes will be affected by the global composite operation.

```
draw stuff
renderingContext.save()
   set composite operation
   draw forests
renderingContext.restore()
go on with drawing
```